# Clear a Default Fields Value After Reset

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am trying to clear a set of field's values on the click of reset button. I am using the below given code in my application

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Sample">
<apex:form id="pageForm">
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" id="thePageBlock" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>                
            <apex:commandButton onclick="clearFieldValues(); return false;"
                  value="Reset"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Customer Details" id="pageBlockSection" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}" id="name" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!account.site}" id="site" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!account.type}" id="accType"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!account.accountNumber}" id="accNo"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <Script>
    function clearFieldValues(){
    document.getElementById("{!$Component.pageForm.thePageBlock.pageBlockSection.name}").value="";
    document.getElementById("{!$Component.pageForm.thePageBlock.pageBlockSection.site}").value="";
    document.getElementById("{!$Component.pageForm.thePageBlock.pageBlockSection.accType}").value="";
    document.getElementById("{!$Component.pageForm.thePageBlock.pageBlockSection.accNo}").value="";
    }
    </Script>

</apex:form>
```

And then the code i have used in my apex class is as given below.

```
public without Sharing class Sample {
public Sample() {
}
public PageReference reset() {
    PageReference pg = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());
    pg.setRedirect(false);
    return pg;
}}
```

The above code clears most of the fields. But fields that are marked required are not getting cleared. They are being populated with the values that were selected before i hit the reset button. Is there something that I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too old to still be relevant to the forum. If you accept an answer or explain how you solved the problem, I will retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the immediate="true" to your apex:commandButton and in this case I think you don't need an apex class for this

[Salesforce Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)

Comment: i tried with immediate="true", but still getting the same issue. With the immediate="true" when i hit the reset button it is not checking if the field is required or not, but the  populated values are not getting cleared, but for the non mandatory fields it is getting cleared...

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: that when i hit the reset button the apex function and the javascript functions are called. But the rest of the fields values are cleared where as the fields that are marked required are not cleared. For ex i select Name as "Mark" and  site as "Rural", when the reset is hit the fields display the same value.

Comment: I edited your code, could you test that? I think it's due to the apex method, which is not necessary in your case. your JS function does what you want.

Comment: i tried it without the apex function but still the same. its only when i remove the Required="true" it works...

Comment: The reason why i say this is when i remove the required for the name field and assign it to some other, say for type, then the name field is cleared but the type field is not. @melmoussaoui

Comment: I tried your code and even with the required true, it clears all fields without rendering the page and it works fine

Comment: thanks a lot... ill check if there is anything else if  i have to change and try with the edited code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14037/discussion-between-melmoussaoui-and-user3197916)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setRedirect to true to flush the view state of your page. From the documentation for setRedirect:

> This type of redirect performs an HTTP GET request, and flushes the view state, which uses POST. If set to false, the redirect is a server-side forward that preserves the view state if and only if the target page uses the same controller and contains the proper subset of extensions used by the source page.

Alternatively you could add a:

```
account = new Account();
```

to your reset() method.

EDIT: I just noticed you aren't actually using the reset method in your controller, you're just calling Javascript. If you want an action on the commandButton for reset, you'd need to add action="{!reset}", which I think would work as an alternative to your javascript clearFieldValues function.